# MarkLogic TDE Xpath values from JSON string array

Tags: arrays, xpath, marklogic, tde

I want to build a a tde with a row with an id and each value of an array in the original document.

I get a row for each element but the values are null and ignored.

Seems if the context is set to anything not an array the ../uri works but never when the context is an array.

I am struggling to find good resources for MarkLogic TDE other than simplistic examples,

**Example document (snippet)**

```
 "instance": {
        "uri": "/A/Uri/of/some/type.json", 
         "types": [
          "a", 
          "b", 
          "c"
      ]
}
```

**Template**

```
{
  "template":{
    "context":"/instance/types",
    "collections":["Collection"],
    "enabled" : true,
    "rows":[
      {
        "schemaName":"namespace",
        "viewName":"uri2types",
        "columns":[
          {
            "name":"uri",
            "scalarType":"anyURI",
            "val":"../uri",
            "nullable":true,
            "invalidValues": "ignore"
          }
          ,
          {
            "name":"type",
            "scalarType":"string",
            "val":"/node()",
            "nullable":true,
            "invalidValues": "ignore"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
     {
        "/A/Uri/of/some/type.json": [
            {
                "row": {
                    "schema": "namespace", 
                    "view": "uri2types", 
                    "data": {
                        "rownum": "1"
                }
            }
        }, 
            {
                "row": {
                    "schema": "namespace", 
                    "view": "uri2types", 
                    "data": {
                        "rownum": "2"
                }
            }
        }, 
            {
                "row": {
                "schema": "namespace", 
                "view": "uri2types", 
                "data": {
                    "rownum": "3"
                }
                }
            }
        ]
        }

**Result Wanted** 


    {
        "/A/Uri/of/some/type.json": [
        {
            "row": {
                    "schema": "namespace", 
                    "view": "uri2types", 
                    "data": {
                        "rownum": "1",
                        "uri":"/A/Uri/of/some/type.json":,
                        "type"="a"

                    }
                }
            }, 
        {
            "row": {
                "schema": "namespace", 
                "view": "uri2types", 
                "data": {
                    "rownum": "2",
                    "uri":"/A/Uri/of/some/type.json":,
                    "type":"b"
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "row": {
                "schema": "namespace", 
                "view": "uri2types", 
                "data": {
                    "rownum": "3",
                    "uri":"/A/Uri/of/some/type.json":,
                    "type":"c"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `/node()` for the `type` column will attempt to get child nodes of the text node containing your type, but a text node doesn't have any child nodes. `data()` or `.` is more appropriate.

The expression `../uri` for the `uri` column does not go up the tree high enough. The full MarkLogic XPath to get to your type values would be `/object-node()/object-node('instance')/array-node('types')/text()`. You need to go up two levels to escape from the surrounding array-node. It can help to rewrite `/instance/types` to `/instance/array-node()/types`:

```
'use strict';

let json = xdmp.toJSON({
  "instance": {
    "uri": "/A/Uri/of/some/type.json", 
    "types": [
      "a", 
      "b", 
      "c"
    ]
  }
});
let tpl = xdmp.toJSON({
  "template":{
    "context":"/instance/array-node()/types",
    "enabled" : true,
    "rows":[
      {
        "schemaName":"namespace",
        "viewName":"uri2types",
        "columns":[
          {
            "name":"uri",
            "scalarType":"anyURI",
            "val":"../../uri",
            "nullable":true,
            "invalidValues": "ignore"
          }
          ,
          {
            "name":"type",
            "scalarType":"string",
            "val":"data()",
            "nullable":true,
            "invalidValues": "ignore"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
tde.validate([tpl]);
tde.nodeDataExtract([json], [tpl]);
```

HTH!

Comment: Thank you that solved it. Both Data() and . worked but the double path thing i am sure I tried previously.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here: `"val":"/node()",`. You're giving a path that starts at the root, rather than the context node. Try this instead:

```
"val":".",
```

Comment: Yes that solved the type appearing but I still can't see the URI data coming across.